# Ember: this.modelFor is not a function (in component)

Tags: ember.js

Question about the Ember method [modelFor](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor)

My attempts to use this in a component have failed:

```
//info component

model(params){
return this.store.createRecord('info'); 
},

user: this.modelFor('user'),
```

this code breaks the entire app with the following error:

```
ember.debug.js:4875 Uncaught TypeError: this.modelFor is not a function
```

I find myself often wanting to use methods in components, or wanting to access multiple models in my component logic -- does anyone know a good resource to educate myself on these best practices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**modelFor** is not a function in components.  You must pass the model into the component via a parameter from the template you are implementing the component in.

```
{{my-component model=model}}
```

[Documentation for Component](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html)

**modelFor** is a function in routes.

[Documentation for Route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html)

**For returning multiple models**

Route

```
model: function() {
  let model1 = this.modelFor('x'),
      model2 = this.modelFor('y');
  return {
    model1: model1,
    model2: model2
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike -- so if you wanted to send a specific model you would first have to invoke it in the route, and then pass it to the component with model=pulledModel

Can you pass multiple objects this way into components? Eg.

{{my-component model=model model2=model2}}

Comment: your model should contain all the objects that you need for that route i.e. model : function() {  return {model1: this.modelFor('x'), model2: this.modelFor('y') }  }